# Display text in the middle of box (vertically)

Tags: html, css

I have a box of fixed width and height, I have a link in it, i want to display the link in the center of box (vertically). Please see this jsfiddle to see the problem

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a5hP3/

Here's code anyway:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <a href="#">put it down, in center of box</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box
{
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
   border:1px solid green;
}

.box a{
      vertical-align:middle; //doesnt work
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the line-height equal to the height:

```
.box
{
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
   border:1px solid green;
   line-height: 300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a5hP3/3

Comment: Thanks, but if the text is long, it creates problem. Cant it be that if its single line, start from middle, if the text get longer, keep it pushing above?

Comment: If you want it to overflow to the top vs the bottom or stay in the middle, I would suggest you add a margin-bottom to your div (without a border), giving the allusion that your text is overflowing towards the top when it's in fact equalizing itself out without overflowing into the margin. In this case you probably want to balance out the margin-bottom with a padding-top of the same value to give it a balanced look when there is little text. Don't forget that your div height should compensate for the padding and margin :)

Comment: thanks, not sure if i understood correctly. could you edit the jsfiddle please?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem with kingjiv's solution. The problem seems to be that once it reaches the end of the div, the overflow is out of the box because the line-height is equal to the height of the div; in fact, this isn't really an overflow, it's just a new line. Please disregard my suggestion.

Comment: Try this  http://jsfiddle.net/a5hP3/17/ `display:inline-block` will treat the whole element as a single element on one line.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

First you can set the line-height of your div equal to its height. Unfortunately for this, you need to remember to update the line-height whenever you change the div's height dimension.

Another solution is to place your text within a div that's styled to be displayed as a table-cell with a vertical alignement. This would be similar to placing your text within a table and setting the vertical alignment on its cells:

```
<div style="outline:#000 thin solid; display:table-cell; height:300px; width:700px; vertical-align:middle">
    Some Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the line-height the same as the container height...

http://jsfiddle.net/a5hP3/1/

Note:  This solution only works when there is one line of text.

Comment: Thanks, but if the text is long, it creates problem (http://jsfiddle.net/a5hP3/7/). Cant it be that if its single line, start from middle, if the text get longer, keep it pushing above?

Answer (score 0):

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a5hP3/6/)

---

CSS:

```
.box
{
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
   border:1px solid green;
   position:relative;
}

.box a{
      display:block;
      position:absolute;
      top:45%;
      left:10% /* adjust based on link width */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem better handled by javascript. (I'm using jQuery here):
http://jsfiddle.net/a5hP3/15/

Comment: box height is same, but the text length is not. If text gets longer, it doesnt work nice (ie. always starts from middle), cant it be that if the text gets longer, keep it pushing up?